# node-gallery "No album found"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am trying to use node-gallery in a Node js/Express/Jade app I am working on.

Having followed instructions from https://github.com/cianclarke/node-gallery, I am currently getting the following error when I load page `localhost:3000/gallery` :

```
{"message":"No album found","error":{"errno":-2,"code":"ENOENT","syscall":"scandir","path":"./resources/photos"}}
```

I am new to all things node js, Express and Jade and I am not sure what the error means and how to solve it?

Comment: what i understand that you are missing some files (the album) in `"./resources/photos"`, make sure you downloaded this folder from the github repository

Comment: @YanMayatskiy, I have downloaded the `resources/photos` folder from the github repo just in case but still the same error. I think the error is to do with the fact that my project is configured to work with View Engine `jade` and NOT `ejs`. Therefore I'm thinking the `album.ejs` template inside node-gallery module is not picked up? What I will do is create an Express/ejs project and see if node-gallery works with that one...

Answer (score 0):

I have re-created my own project to render views using `ejs` instead of `jade` and now `node-gallery` is working okay.